# In place editor for blocks

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm trying to make certain blocks editable for users with a certain role. I'm looking for a module which would provide an in-place editor for blocks. There's a module for this called [Block Edit](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_edit) but there isnt a drupal 7 release. Is there any other module similar to this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [Boxes](https://www.drupal.org/project/boxes) module. Which supports in-place editing.

> Boxes module is a reimplementation of the custom blocks (boxes) that
>   the core block module provides. It is a proof of concept for what a
>   re-worked block module could do.
>
> The module assumes that custom blocks are configuration, and not
>   content. This means that it is a reasonable action to ask for all
>   blocks at one time, this is in fact exactly what the core block module
>   does.
>
> Boxes provides an inline interface for editing blocks, allowing you to
>   change the contents of blocks without going to an admin page.
>
> Boxes provides exportables for its blocks via the (required) Chaos
>   tools module. This allows modules to provide blocks in code that can
>   be overwritten in the UI.
>
> Chaos tools is required to use Boxes.

Be sure to look at the module page for full information.